# linking pgi compiled library with gcc linker

Tags: linker, undefined-reference, openacc, pgi

I would like to know how to link a pgc++ compiled code (blabla.a) with a main code compiled with c++ or g++ GNU compiler.
For the moment linking with default gnu c++ linker gives errors like:
 undefined reference to `__pgio_initu'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the previous person already pointed out, PGI supports G++ name mangling when using the `pgc++` command. Judging from this output, I'm guessing that you're linking with g++ rather than pgc++. I've had the most success when using pgc++ as the linker so that it finds the PGI libraries. If that's not an option, you can link an executable with `pgc++ -dryrun` to get the full link line and past the `-L` and `-l` options from there to get the same libraries.

Comment: @MedAissa Can you please mark this answer as the solution for anyone who happens to search for this same problem in the future? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Different C++ compilers use different [name-mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) conventions
to generate the names that they expose to the linker, so the member function
name `int A::foo(int)` will be emitted to to the linker by compiler A as one string
of goobledegook, and by compiler B as quite a different string of goobledegook,
and the linker has no way of knowing they refer to the same function. Hence
you can't link object files produced by different C++ compilers unless they
employ the same name-mangling convention (*and quite possibly not even then*: name-mangling
is just one aspect of [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) compatibility.)

That being said, according to [this document](https://www.pgroup.com/lit/articles/insider/v4n1a2.htm), 
PGC++ supported name-mangling compatibility with g++ 3-and-half years ago, *provided that PGI C++ compiler was invoked with precisely the command `pgc++` or `pgcpp --gnu`.* It may be that the library you are dealing with was not built in that specific way, or perhaps was built with an older PGI C++ compiler.

Anyhow, if g++ compiles the headers of your `blabla.a` and emits different
symbols from the ones in `blabla.a`, you can't link g++ code with `blabla.a`.
You'd need to rebuild `blabla.a` with g++, which perhaps is not an option.