# c - Dynamically linking a PGI OpenACC-enabled library with gcc

Tags: gcc, linker, openacc, pgi, pgi-accelerator

Previously, I asked a question regarding the creation of a **static library** with PGI and linking it to a program that is built with gcc: [c - Linking a PGI OpenACC-enabled library with gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213176/c-linking-a-pgi-openacc-enabled-library-with-gcc)

Now, I have the same question but **dynamically**. How can I built a program with gcc while my library is **dynamically** built with PGI?

And also, considering following facts:

- I want both of them to recognize same OpenMP pragma and routines too. For instance, when I use OpenMP critical regions in the library, the whole program should be serialized at that section.
- OpenACC pragmas are used in the library that was built with PGI.
- Load library completely dynamic in my application. I mean using `dlopen` to open lib and `dlsym` to find functions.
- I also want my threads to be able to simultaneously access GPU for data tranfer and/or computations. For more details see following code snippets.

For instance, building following lib and main code emits this error: `call to cuMemcpyHtoDAsync returned error 1: Invalid value`

---

**Note:** When building following codes, I intentionally used LibGOMP (`-lgomp`) instead of PGI's OpenMP library (`-lpgmp`) for both cases, lib and main.

---

Lib code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openacc.h>
#include <omp.h>

double calculate_sum(int n, double *a) {
    double sum = 0;
    int i;

    #pragma omp critical
    {
        printf("Num devices: %d\n", acc_get_num_devices(acc_device_nvidia));

        #pragma acc enter data copyin(a[0:n])

        #pragma acc parallel 
        #pragma acc loop
        for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
            sum += a[i];
        }

        #pragma acc exit data delete(a[0:n])
    }

    return sum;
}


int ret_num_dev(int index) {
    int dev = acc_get_num_devices(acc_device_nvidia);
    if(dev == acc_device_nvidia)
        printf("Num devices: %d - Current device: %d\n", dev, acc_get_device());
    return dev;
}
```

Built library with following commands:

`pgcc -acc -ta=nvidia:nordc -fPIC -c libmyacc.c`

`pgcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libctest.so.1 -o libmyacc.so -L/opt/pgi/linux86-64/16.5/lib -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5 -laccapi -laccg -laccn -laccg2 -ldl -lcudadevice -lgomp -lnuma -lpthread -lnspgc -lpgc -lm -lgcc -lc -lgcc libmyacc.o`

---

Main code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>


#define N 1000

// to make sure library is loaded just once for whole program
static void *lib_handle = NULL;
static int lib_loaded = 0;
static double (*calculate_sum2)(int , double *);

void call_lib_so() {

    // load library just once and init the function pointer
    // to function in the library.
    if(lib_loaded == 0) {
        lib_loaded = 1;
        char *error;

        lib_handle = dlopen("/home/millad/temp/gcc-pgi/libmyacc.so", RTLD_NOW);
        if (!lib_handle) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
            exit(1);
        }

        calculate_sum2 = (double (*)(int , double *)) dlsym(lib_handle, "calculate_sum");
        if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL)  {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error);
            exit(1);
        }
    }


    // execute the function per call
    int n = N, i;
    double *a = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        a[i] = 1.0 * i;
    double sum = (*calculate_sum2)(n, a);
    free(a);
    printf("-------- SUM: %.3f\n", sum);



//  dlclose(lib_handle);
}


extern double calculate_sum(int n, double *a);

int main() {

    // allocation and initialization of an array
    double *a = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double) * N);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++) {
        a[i] = (i+1) * 1.0;
    }

    // access and run OpenACC region with all threads
    #pragma omp parallel
    call_lib_so();

    return 0;
}
```

And built my main code with following command using gcc as described by Mat in my previous question:

`gcc f1.c -L/opt/pgi/linux86-64/16.5/lib -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5 -L. -laccapi -laccg -laccn -laccg2 -ldl -lcudadevice -lgomp -lnuma -lpthread -lnspgc -lpgc -lm -lgcc -lc -lgcc -lmyacc`

---

Am I doing something wrong? Are above steps correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works correctly for me. I tried to use what you listed but needed to remove the "libctest.so", change the location where dlopen gets the so, and add "-DN=1024" on the gcc compilation line. After that, it compiled and ran fine.

```
% pgcc -acc -ta=nvidia:nordc -fPIC -c libmyacc.c -V16.5                            
% pgcc -shared -o libmyacc.so -L/opt/pgi/linux86-64/16.5/lib -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5 -laccapi -laccg -laccn -laccg2 -ldl -lcudadevice -lgomp -lnuma -lpthread -lnspgc -lpgc -lm -lgcc -lc -lgcc libmyacc.o -V16.5
% gcc f1.c -L/proj/pgi/linux86-64/16.5/lib -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5 -L. -laccapi -laccg -laccn -laccg2 -ldl -lcudadevice -lgomp -lnuma -lpthread -lnspgc -lpgc -lm -lgcc -lc -lgcc -lmyacc -DN=1024
% ./a.out
Num devices: 8
-------- SUM: 523776.000
```

Comment: Thanks @mat-colgrove. Sorry about `libctest.so`. It was a typo. On my end, I changed it to `libmyacc.so` after copy-paste it here and worked. **However**, I made a mistake on options that passed to `gcc`. When I enable OpenMP using `-fopenmp` on gcc (line 3 on your answer) and remove `omp critical` line in the library, **sometimes** it gives me `call to cuMemFreeHost returned error 1: Invalid value` error.

Comment: Try adding "-nomp" to the PGI options.  PGI's and GNU's OpenMP runtime are not compatible which may be causing your issue.  Note that while this works for me, the binary did periodically get a seg fault.  Though, this also occurred when I put macro guards around the OpenACC code and built with just GNU so I don't think it's related nor did I investigate further.

Comment: Thanks Mat for your help on this question. I added `-nomp` to compile the library. However, when I call my function on the library in a loop, I get `Segmentation fault` error. I simply call `calculate_sum` like 1000 times, but it stops with error on first 7th or 8th iteration. This is what GDB shows me: [GDB Output](https://paste.ee/p/fLfOw). Any ideas?

Comment: And this is my main file and library: [Source](https://paste.ee/p/2bmxy)