# how to connect pgfortran(has OpenAcc direvative ) with python by f2py

Tags: python, fortran, f2py, pgi

use f2py to connect python and Fortran language.
f2py website
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/f2py/

Fortran before used gfortran and pgfortran(PGI) integrate OpenMP both work.

makefile file is below

gfortran version

```
    gfortran -c -fopenmp mod_readfile.f90 -lgomp
    f2py -c  mod_readfile.f90 --f90flags="-fopenmp" -lgomp -m mod_readfile
```

pgfortran version

```
    pgfortran -c -mp mod_readfile.f90  -lgomp
    f2py -c  mod_readfile.f90 --fcompiler=pg --f90flags="-mp" -lgomp -m mod_readfile
```

then !$omp direvative in Fortran was recognized

I want to extend it to OpenAcc, and !$acc is also be recognized, but it fails, because openacc is incorporated in pgfortran(PGI), so I use makefile as below

```
    pgfortran -c -acc mod_readfile.f90 -lcublas -lcudart -lgomp
    f2py -c  mod_readfile.f90 --fcompiler=pg --f90flags="-acc"  -m mod_readfile -lcublas -lcudart -lgomp
```

before I checked that

```
pgfortran -c -acc mod_readfile.f90
```

works well separately. 
but when it manipulated as module of python it has some problem. also confused these flags(-lcublas -lcudart -lgomp), below doesn't work because lacking -lgomp flag

```
    gfortran -c -fopenmp mod_readfile.f90 
    f2py -c  mod_readfile.f90 --f90flags="-fopenmp" -m mod_readfile
```

after google find [Using F2Py with OpenACC gives import error in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40267183/using-f2py-with-openacc-gives-import-error-in-python)
compiled with acc (gfortran)and f2py, 
but I still want to know is it possible to have pgfortran with acc to connect with python? which compile flags should I use?
thanks

Comment: The name of the language is **Fortran**.  It has been spelled as **Fortran** since 1990.

Answer (score 1):

Try compiling with "-ta=tesla:nordc".  RDC stands for relocatable device code which requires the device code to be linked with a device linker.  While we (PGI) have added support for using RDC in shared objects, I'm not sure the process f2py uses so may not be using pgfortran to create the shared object and hence miss the device link step.

The caveat of using nordc is that you wont be able to use device module data (via the "declare" directive) outside of the module itself, nor call device routines (via the "routine" directive).